# Assembly multiple push does not take into account the push list order

Tags: assembly, stack, arm

I have 3 parameters, and I store them in three different registers, say R1, R8 and R9. I found out that once the multiple push is done PUSH {r1,r8... etc} what I find in memory is exactly the same as when I write PUSH {r9, r8, R1}.

The values indeed differ, R9 holds 1000, r1 and r8 are both below 50.  Why aren't they pushed in the order I wrote in the instruction?

Indeed even if I take the order r8, r9, r1 it will again store them in the stack as r9, r8, r1 bottom to top.

I thought `PUSH {r1,r8,r9}` won't be the same as `PUSH {r9,r8,r1}`.

Comment: The machine encoding is a bitmap of which regs to push.  There isn't room to encode a variable order as well, since that would take many more bits.  It would probably be good if the assembler refused to accept out-of-order pushes like `push {r9,r8,r1}`, instead of silently ignoring the programmer's misplaced hope that push order is controllable.

Comment: @PeterCordes So I can't store in the stack from bottom to top 20 11 1000, regardless of how I'm applying the multiple push and instead I'll always receive 1000 11 20 bottom-top in the stack? I know I can do it by getting a value in a register, pushing, value - push, the  third value - push but that's not the task. In the task they want optimisation and if I manage to multiple push 3 registers at once in the proper order, i'll save 2 instructions which'll satisfy it.

Comment: So move the data into appropriately-ordered registers first then ;)

Comment: Yup, I'm doing it right now, let's see... :)

Comment: Done, works as charm. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't say what processor you're using, but the assembly looks like an ARM of some description.

As mentioned in the description [ARM - Push](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Babefbce.html)

> PUSH and POP are synonyms for STMDB and LDM (or LDMIA), with the base register sp (r13), 
>   and the adjusted address written back to the base register. PUSH and POP are the preferred mnemonic in these cases.
>   **Registers are stored on the stack in numerical order, with the lowest numbered register at the lowest address**

If for some reason you do need to store things in a specific order on the stack you would have to use multiple instructions.

For the why is that the case question. As Peter Cordes said in a comment, it's due to the register list being stored as a bitfield in the instruction. From the ARM ARM (ARM Architecture Reference Manual) the encoding of the LDM/STM instruction is

```
Bit 31 -- 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 -- 16 15 -------- 0
     COND     1  0  0  P  U  S  W  L    Rn      Registers
```

From this it's clear to see that storing r0, r8 and r9 would set bits 0, 8, and 9 (0x0301 in the low 16 bits of the instruction) regardless of the order they're written in code.

Comment: The lowest numerical order in the reg_list PUSH {reg_list} or R0, R1, R2 <=> R1,R2,R0 <=> R2,R0,R1... which will be always stored as R0,R1,R2 because 0<1<2 and R0 will be at the bottom of the stack? It is ARM. I tried to push 3 combinations, r9, r8, r0; I tried r0, r8, r9 and r8, r0, r9 and the result I get is always r9 at the bottom, r8 in the middle (correct) and r0 on top (what I don't want, should be at the bottom). In all the combinations. I tried storing the value of R0 into R9, and the one of R9 to R0, stores the same again, I've literary no clue on why that happens.

Comment: It stores the lowest numbered register from the list you pass, irrespective of order of the list at the lowest address. So if you have a decrementing stack (things are pushed into lower addresses), r0 will be at the top, then r8, then r9. This is what you're seeing. 
If they must be in the order you specify then `PUSH r0` then `PUSH r8` then `PUSH r9`

Comment: @KDX2: See my comment on your question.  It happens because different push orders are not encodeable.

Comment: @Colin__s
Thank you VERY MUCH! I understood it. Well, I'll try to directly store the values in the proper regs and i'll try again, otherwise - the longer way. Thank you again. I'd like to mark both answers as best but I can't, thank you.